# Did any one try openstack cisco avos?

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I tried to see how openstack cisco avos is going to look like. I have followed the instructions mentioned in https://github.com/CiscoSystems/avos

No errors while running it through virtual environment(./run_tests.sh --runserver localhost:9000), but not able to see AVOS tab upon login.

My envrironemnt is having 3 node sertup comprises controller, compute and storage. I tried to run this on controller node.

Any additional configurations required or am i missing something?
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest what was the IP address you entered in your web browser?

Whenever I tried AVOS I used a virtual environment and issued the following command:

```
tools/with_venv.py python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

To connect to the dashboard, I entered the IP address of my eth0 network interface  with ':8080' added at the end (e.g. 192.168.2.1:8080)  in my web browser and this opened up the dashboard for me to login. After I logged in there was an option for AVOS under the System section when you clicked on Admin.

Are you getting any errors in the logs? I think at the start I was having problems where some of the static AVOS files weren't being found, I was able to see a 404 error in the openstack-dashboard-access_log

I noticed that you used ' --runserver ' which didn't work for me whenever I tried it.